# python code convention using pylint

Tags: python, conventions, pylint

I'm trying out pylint to check my source code for conventions. Somehow some variable names are matched with the regex for constants (`const-rgx`) instead of the variable name regex (`variable-rgx`). How to match the variable name with `variable-rgx`? Or should I extend `const-rgx` with my `variable-rgx` stuff?

e.g.
`C0103: 31: Invalid name "settings" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z1-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Somehow some variable names are matched with the regex for constants (const-rgx) instead of the variable name regex (variable-rgx).

Are those variables declared on module level? Maybe that's why they are treated as constants (at least that's how they should be declared, according to PEP-8).

Comment: +1 for answering the real question, i.e. about which regex is being used, not the actual regex.

Comment: They are indeed declared on module level!

Comment: the most annoying warning comes when this check pops up in the ´if __name__ == '__main__'´ block, but it is correct since all the variables there are still on the module level. The easiest way to overcome the problem is to have only call to a separate main(...) function

Answer (score 10):

I just disable that warning because I don't follow those naming conventions.

To do that, add this line to the top of you module:

```
# pylint: disable-msg=C0103
```

If you want to disable that globally, then add it to the pylint command:

```
python lint.py --disable-msg=C0103 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(should match (([A-Z_][A-Z1-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
```

like you said that is the const-rgx that is only matching UPPERCASE names, or names surrounded by double underscores.

the variables-rgx is

```
([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$)
```

if your variable is called 'settings'  that indeed should match the variables-rgx

I can think of only 2 reasons for this..
either settings is a **constant** or it is  a bug in PyLint.