# How do I tell PyLint "it's a variable, not a constant" to stop message C0103?

Tags: python, pylint

I have a module-level variable in my Python 2.6 program named "_log", which PyLint complains about:

```
C0103: Invalid name "_log" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
```

Having read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709490/python-code-convention-using-pylint/709709#709709) I understand why it's doing this: it thinks the variable is a constant and applies the constant regex. However, I beg to differ: I think it's a variable. How do I tell PyLint that, so it doesn't complain? How does PyLint determine whether it's a variable or a constant - does it just treat all module-level variables as constants?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
# pylint: disable-msg=C0103
```

Put it in the scope where you want these warnings to be ignored. You can also make the above an end-of-line comment, to disable the message only for that line of code.

IIRC it is true that pylint interprets all module-level variables as being 'constants'.

newer versions of pylint will take this line instead

```
# pylint: disable=C0103
```

Comment: Thanks. I also added `# pylint: enable-msg=C0103` afterwards so that the rest of the code still gets checked.

Comment: Where do I put this code in order to disable this error message in all my Python source files?

Comment: `IIRC it is true that pylint interprets all module-level variables as being 'constants'.` - Why still they didn't make the Pylint to differentiate the `variable` & `constants`? Is there any technical challenge is there?.

Comment: @JaiK well, there *is no* technical difference between constants and (other) variables in Python, so I couldn't think of any better way to distinguish the two...

Comment: @lenz  How about not assuming a variable is a constant if the code has multiple assignments to it?

Comment: @gherson yeah, that might be a nice heuristic: If it's only assigned once, then it's a constant and should be all-caps (and vice versa). If it's assigned to multiple times it's a variable – but at the module level this would mean it's a global variable, which is something linters complain about anyway.

Answer (score 24):

You can also specify a comma separated list of "good-names" that are always allowed in your pylintrc, eg:

```
[BASIC]
good-names=_log
```

Answer (score 20):

Seems to me a bit of refactor might help. Pylint in looking at this as a module, so it would be reasonable not to expect to see variables at this level. Conversely it doesn't complain about vars in classes or functions. The following paradigm seems quite common and solves the issue:

```
def main():
    '''Entry point if called as an executable'''
    _log = MyLog()  # . . .

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This has the benefit that if you have some useful classes, I can import them without running your main. The **__name__** is that of the module so the "if" fails.

Comment: Not all programs are scripts that have a main function, such as Django urls.py files.

Comment: This variable only exists in the function. It's not module-level variable.

Answer (score 12):

In newer versions of pylint this line is now

```
# pylint: disable=C0103
```

the enable message is as simple

```
# pylint: enable=C0103
```

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have indicated you can disable a specific PyLint warning (such C0103) as by including the following line:

```
# pylint: disable=C0103
```

but this generates the `Locally disabling invalid-name` warning.  Note that this secondary warning could be useful if you want to be reminded of the disabled warning.  If you want to disable the warning silently without altering your config file (which would disable the warning globally) you can use:

```
# pylint: disable=I0011,C0103
```

Note that PyLint does not issue a warning that you are disabling I0011!

Answer (score 2):

If you disable a message locally in your file then Pylint will report another different warning!

```
Locally disabling invalid-name (C0103) [I:locally-disabled]
```

If your intention is for a clean lint run, and surely that should be the target otherwise why are you bothering, then you can disable that message and the corresponding locally-enabled message in your configuration file:

```
disable=locally-disabled, locally-enabled
```