# Invalid constant name when using lib argparse in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, flake8

```
import argparse
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser(description="Test Massage")
```

flake8 in vim accurate error

test.py|4 col 1 warning| [invalid-name] Invalid constant name "parser"

Comment: I think [this solution](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/847) is more robust, more helpful, and better explains the issue than the answer given by @Liviu.

Comment: @Mike I mostly agree (helpful explanation, some solution), except I do not see the better solution since adding parameters to pylint everywhere is not really practical in my view ... 

Instead, could you kindly answer THIS question ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using `Pylint`and I solved it moving the assignment in a function (make a dedicated function to parse the command line). I guess it treats the module level variables as constants, like Pylint also does, because it doesn't make much sense to declare them there and it's much easier to apply a simple rule than to really detect if it is a constant.

Comment: More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885251/how-do-i-tell-pylint-its-a-variable-not-a-constant-to-stop-message-c0103
(and the linked questions)