# Constant name doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming stylepylint(invalid-name)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm attempting to use the OpenCv library, but I got the error that there was no library installed when it was installed. I fixed that issue by putting 
`"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2"`on my settings. However, now I get a warning when using a variable. The warning displayed is `Constant name "img" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming stylepylint(invalid-name)`
I'm using VS Code on MacOSX.

If I delete what I added to my settings the warnings go away, but doing so stops me from being able to use OpenCv.

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg', 0)
```

The expected results would just be code without any warnings

Answer (score 3):

To disable this error system-wide, you'll need to add this to your VS Code settings (`...`'s represent already existing stuff, unneeded if doesn't exist):

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [..."disable=C0103"...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Include comment

```
# pylint: disable=C0103
```

in your code file (per [How do I tell PyLint "it's a variable, not a constant" to stop message C0103?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885251/how-do-i-tell-pylint-its-a-variable-not-a-constant-to-stop-message-c0103)).

(No word yet on how to disable that error message system-wide.)

Answer (score 2):

Yo can create a *.pylintrc* file on the root of your project so you can ignore the rule:

```
[MASTER]
disable=
    C0103, # uppercase naming style
    CXXXX, # add ad many as you need
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of Python's PEP rules, you must use capital letters in variable names. Like a `IMG = cv2.imread('image.jpg', 0)`

Comment: "Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
Variable names follow the same convention as function names." -- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

So, no, the problem is that PyLint considers the variable a constant, which I would say is due to the lack of another assignment, but I have the same problem with a variable assigned more than once in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the below from the **settings.json** file on **VS Code** and it worked

```
// setting.json 

"pylint.args": [
   "--disable=missing-module-docstring",
   "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
   "--disable=missing-function-docstring"
   "--disable=C0103" // <--- this one
 ],
```